# jquery select div inside div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get this to alert only the div clicked on, vs alerting the div clicked and then the container div's.  when I click on the third div I would like it to only alert "third".  thanks for the help.

```
<div id="first">   
    <div id="second">
        <div id="third">
            third div
        </div>
        second div
    </div>
    first div
</div>

$("div").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: @James Mohler: As many questions as there are, "div" is a very poor tag. Please don't use it, especially not on old questions.

Answer (score 4):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FMfyE/)

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

that will do it.

Answer (score 2):

[event.stopPropagation();](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$("div").click(function(event) {
    alert(this.id);
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div").click(function(event) {
    alert(this.id);
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    return false;
})
```